# rails7 heroku deployment failure (internal server error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-7

trying to deploy my rails7 app to heroku The home screen is coming up but whenever I click on a link to another page I get a screen saying "sorry something went wrong". "if your the application owner check the logs". an in the logs it says
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: That would be an error within your code most likely. Test it locally, if it still works then I suppose you could enable more verbose logging in the Rails app on Heroku. We have nothing to go off here so you're unlikely to get any help without a specific error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Rails 7 app started up locally fine but failed on Heroku deployment because of class naming errors. Note that Rails 7 uses [Zeitwerk as its autoloader](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html). You can test this locally by running: `bundle exec rake zeitwerk:check`